# File attachment XML as HTML

Tags: apex, xml, file-storage

I have a file attachment that I want to display as html, this attachment is created as a note and Attachment after a response from an API Call.
The file attachment is an xml that I link at the moment of the attachment to an xls file by doing this

```
String content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>......XML FROM RESPONSE....';
String report_xml = '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=015N0000000Ylyq" ?>';
content = report_xml + content;
Blob report_content = Blob.valueOf(content);
Attachment attach = new Attachment();
attach.Body = report_content;
attach.Name = 'report.xml';
attach.ParentId = '006XXXXXXXX';
attach.ContentType = 'text/xml';
insert attach;
```

however at the moment of viewing the file it download instead of rendering on the browser.
I am working in a different work where they have done something similar but for some reason the second org when the user clicks on the xml file it renders properly in the browser. 
I am not sure what else I need to do to get this working.
Both Orgs have the same config in file security:

[image: file security]

Comment: Huh?? You question is not very clear on both the problem and the question you are asking

Comment: @Eric A salesforce org has xml file attachments, when clicked to view it renders an HTML page. On a new org I have a File attach as XML I have linked to an XLS (Similar what the first org has done), when I click on view the attachment, it downloads and not display on browser, I want to know what makes the second org behaviour different to the first one. Is this more clear?